# Problema com checkbox com dependências e outras checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

Boa tarde a todos.
Tenho um sistema em que estou setando as permissões em que o perfil pode ter acesso em uma página via checkbox para cada módulo do sistema. Tenho uma página com form em que seto essas permissões e no submit ele pega uma variável "permissions" e atribui a tabela daquele perfil de usuários as permissões correspondentes. Pois cada opção de checkbox tem um value que corresponde a um id da tabela de permissões no banco de dados.

Cada módulo possui as seguintes opções de permissão:

- Todas as permissões (marca todas as abaixo)
- Página "base" (marca Página "base" e Listar)
- Listar (marca somente Listar)
- Ver informações de um único item (marca somente Ver informações de um único item)
- Criar (Marca Página "base", Listar, Ver informações de um único item e ele próprio)
- Atualizar(Marca Página "base", Listar, Ver informações de um único item e ele próprio)
- Deletar (Marca Listar e ele próprio).

Cada módulo tem dependências em outros módulos também.

Mas o problema é que por exemplo no módulo de **clientes**. Se eu marco as opções: Página "base" e Criar, ao eu desmarcar Criar ele desmarca as opções dependentes de Página "base" também e não devia. Como solucionar isso?

Utilizo funções de jQuery e Javascript para fazer as opções de checked e uncheck nos checkbox.

Segue link para ver na prática: https://jsfiddle.net/lfinfor/w4c3jdzk/9/

Segue o código abaixo:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    $("#check_all" + i).click(function() {
        // Address
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "check_all1") {
            if (this.checked) {
                changeCheckboxAll("address", "true");
                $("#city-all").prop("checked", true);
                $("#state-all").prop("checked", true);
                $("#country-all").prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $("#city-all").prop("checked", false);
                $("#state-all").prop("checked", false);
                $("#country-all").prop("checked", false);
                changeCheckboxAll("address", "false");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#check_all" + i).click(function() {
        // Client 1, 2, 10, 14
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "check_all14") {
            if (this.checked) {
                changeCheckboxAll("client", "true");
                $("#address-all").prop("checked", true);
                $("#address-store").prop("checked", true);
                $("#address-update").prop("checked", true);
                $("#answer-store").prop("checked", true);
                $("#answer-update").prop("checked", true);
                $("#profile-all").prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                changeCheckboxAll("client", "false");
                $("#address-all").prop("checked", false);
                $("#address-store").prop("checked", false);
                $("#address-update").prop("checked", false);
                $("#answer-store").prop("checked", false);
                $("#answer-update").prop("checked", false);
                $("#profile-all").prop("checked", false);
            }
        }
    });
}


$("input").on("click", function() {

 // Module Address
           // All operations dependencies this module
            if (this.checked) {
                changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'true');
            } else {
                changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'false');
            }
            // Permission homepage of a module
            if (this.id == 'address-index') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxIndex('address', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('address', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxIndex('address', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission List of elements of a module
            if (this.id == 'address-all') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxListAll('address', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxListAll('address', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission Store
            if (this.id == 'address-store') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxStore('address', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxStore('address', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission Update
            if (this.id == 'address-update') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxUpdate('address', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxUpdate('address', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission for excluse
            if (this.id == 'address-delete') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxDelete('address', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxDelete('address', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress('address', 'false');
                }
            }


 // Module Client
           // All operations dependencies this module
            if (this.checked) {
                changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'true');
            } else {
                changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'false');
            }
            // Permission homepage of a module
            if (this.id == 'client-index') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxIndex('client', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxIndex('client', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission List of elements of a module
            if (this.id == 'client-all') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxListAll('client', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxListAll('client', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission Store
            if (this.id == 'client-store') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxStore('client', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxStore('client', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission Update
            if (this.id == 'client-update') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxUpdate('client', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxUpdate('client', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'false');
                }
            }
            // Permission for excluse
            if (this.id == 'client-delete') {
                if (this.checked) {
                    changeCheckboxDelete('client', 'true');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'true');
                } else {
                    changeCheckboxDelete('client', 'false');
                    changeCheckboxDependenciesClients('client', 'false');
                }
            }

 });




function changeCheckbox(module_slug, bool) {
    if (bool == "false") {
        $("#" + module_slug + "-index").prop("checked", false);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-all").prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $("#" + module_slug + "-index").prop("checked", true);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-all").prop("checked", true);
    }
}

    // Permissions to homepage of a module
    function changeCheckboxIndex(module_slug, bool) {
        if (bool == 'false') {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-index').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-index').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }


    // Permissions to list all elements of a module
    function changeCheckboxListAll(module_slug, bool) {
        if (bool == 'false') {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }


    // Permissions to exclude elements of a module
    function changeCheckboxDelete(module_slug, bool) {
        if (bool == 'false') {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-delete').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-delete').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }

    // Permissions for Update data
    function changeCheckboxUpdate(module_slug, bool) {
        if (bool == 'false') {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-index').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-view').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-update').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-index').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-view').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-update').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
    // Permissions for Store data
    function changeCheckboxStore(module_slug, bool) {
        if (bool == 'false') {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-index').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-view').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-store').prop('checked', false);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#' + module_slug + '-index').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-view').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-store').prop('checked', true);
            $('#' + module_slug + '-all').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }

function changeCheckboxAll(module_slug, bool) {
    if (bool == "false") {
        $("#" + module_slug + "-index").prop("checked", false);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-all").prop("checked", false);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-view").prop("checked", false);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-store").prop("checked", false);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-update").prop("checked", false);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-delete").prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        $("#" + module_slug + "-index").prop("checked", true);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-all").prop("checked", true);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-view").prop("checked", true);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-store").prop("checked", true);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-update").prop("checked", true);
        $("#" + module_slug + "-delete").prop("checked", true);
    }
}

    // Permissions dependencies of module Clients
    function changeCheckboxDependenciesClients(module_slug, bool) {
        if (bool == 'false') {
            $('#address-all').prop('checked', false);
            $('#address-store').prop('checked', false);
            $('#address-update').prop('checked', false);
            $('#answer-store').prop('checked', false);
            $('#answer-update').prop('checked', false);
            $('#profile-all').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('#address-all').prop('checked', true);
            $('#address-store').prop('checked', true);
            $('#address-update').prop('checked', true);
            $('#answer-store').prop('checked', true);
            $('#answer-update').prop('checked', true);
            $('#profile-all').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }

    // Permissions dependencies of module Clients
    function changeCheckboxDependenciesAddress(module_slug, bool) {
        if (bool == 'false') {
            $("#city-all").prop("checked", false);
            $("#state-all").prop("checked", false);
            $("#country-all").prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            $("#city-all").prop("checked", true);
            $("#state-all").prop("checked", true);
            $("#country-all").prop("checked", true);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="permission-clients">
            <div class="col-md-6  hide-1">
                <div class="box-modules">
                    <div class="title-modules">Permissões em Endereços</div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_all1" class="filled-in">
                        <label for="check_all1">Todas as permissões</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="address-index" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="1" value="1">
                        <label for="address-index">Página "base"</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="address-all" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="1" value="2">
                        <label for="address-all">Listar</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="address-view" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="1" value="3">
                        <label for="address-view">Ver informações de um único item</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="address-store" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="1" value="4">
                        <label for="address-store">Criar</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="address-update" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="1" value="5">
                        <label for="address-update">Atualizar</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="address-delete" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="1" value="6">
                        <label for="address-delete">Deletar</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6  hide-14">
                <div class="box-modules">
                    <div class="title-modules" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top:10px;">Permissões em Clientes</div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check_all14" class="filled-in">
                        <label for="check_all14">Todas as permissões</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="client-index" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="14" value="79">
                        <label for="client-index">Página "base"</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="client-all" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="14" value="80">
                        <label for="client-all">Listar</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="client-view" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="14" value="81">
                        <label for="client-view">Ver informações de um único item</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="client-store" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="14" value="82">
                        <label for="client-store">Criar</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="client-update" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="14" value="83">
                        <label for="client-update">Atualizar</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 iten-modules">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="client-delete" name="permissions[]" class="filled-in" onclick="14" value="84">
                        <label for="client-delete">Deletar</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Eu vou posteriormente criar uma só função para independente do módulo, fazer as operações de check/uncheck de cada um - ou seja, mesclar // Module Client e // Module Address em uma só função.)

Comment: Posso contribuir dando uma sugestão, que acho que deixa o código mais limpo e melhor de ser lido: você pode usar o mesmo código para alterar múltiplos elementos, em vez de fazer em separado. Por exemplo: `$('#address-all, #address-store').prop('checked', false);`... é só separar os seletores com uma vírgula.

Comment: Obrigado vou implementar isso para ficar mais legível tbm.